# Im trying to make a request to a spring endpoint role access

Tags: spring, spring-webclient

so i have a controller with two methods/mappings:

```
@DeleteMapping("/api/delete")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('DEVELOPER')")
public void delete() {}

@GetMapping("/api/get")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
public void get() {}
```

with a security config as follows:

....

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/**", "/api/v1/**").hasRole("USER")
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/v1/**").hasRole("DEVELOPER")
```

....

my question if im trying to call these two endpoints from another spring application, using webclient. But i keep getting not authorised.

How do i set the roles in the webcleint

```
webClient.delete()
        .uri(deleteUrl)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Void.class);
```

I guess i would need to set a token on the request?

Comment: You didn't mention what you're using for authentication, but from your comment on the token it sounds like you're using some variety of oauth.  You simply need to call it with a token that is both valid and contains the scopes for the developer and user roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if the server uses tokens (presumably Bearer JWT) they need to be added to the request as follows:

```
webClient.delete()
    .uri(deleteUrl)
    .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(token))
    .bodyToMono(Void.class);;
```